# Is there a standard list of Default Answers which are used in Likert 'type' Scales

Tags: survey

I have always had some trouble deciding what to use as the default answers when using Likert 'type' scales.

**Is there a default list of accepted answers to particular types of questions which are used by survey designers?** e.g. "Level of effect", "Amount you agree with",  "Make you act" "Level of Awareness" type questions.

I accept that there is a huge range of types of questions but if there was some sort of semi standardised list of 5, 6 and 7 point answers it would be very handy. In many cases I have difficulty thinking of just one of the answers or the correct terminology or syntax which should be used to ensure that each of the answers are 'appropriately distributed'... if that makes sense

For many types of questions there are existing examples online e.g.

> What most clearly reflects your political leaning?
>
> - Strong Democrat
> - Not so strong Democrat
> - Independent leaning Democrat
> - Independent
> - Independent leaning Republican
> - Not so strong Republican
> - Strong Republican
> - Other
> - Don't know

Or

> The county is on the right economic path
>
> - Strongly agree
> - Agree
> - Neither or N/A
> - Disagree
> - Strongly Disagree

However in other instances it is more difficult to figure out what answers should be used

> In your opinion, does a perceptible level of bias in a particular news
>   story affect the overall level of credibility the story has?
>
> - Yes, most definitely
> - Yes, to some degree
> - Yes, a slight effect
> - No, ????
> - No,not really
> - No, not at all

Any help or links to resources would be seriously appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are links to several lists of common Likert-type response anchors (the first link provides a nice variety):

http://www.clemson.edu/centers-institutes/tourism/documents/sample-scales.pdf

http://www.rpgroup.org/sites/default/files/Surveys%20Interactive%20Activity%20-%20Examples%20of%20Likert%20scales.pdf

And these links provide suggestions regarding designing these scales and may help you determine how to adapt the anchor options from the first set of links:
http://www.uwex.edu/ces/4h/evaluation/documents/wordingforratingscales.pdf

http://surveynet.ac.uk/sqb/datacollection/likertfactsheet.pdf

http://academics.lmu.edu/spee/officeofassessment/surveysevaluation/surveydesign/step3determinetheformatoftheresponseoptions/

http://www.dism.ssri.duke.edu/pdfs/Tipsheet%20-%20Response%20Scales.pdf